Impact of db_owner Permission on distributed transactions in ASP.NET Core 8 Web API using Entity Framework Core
I am working with an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API that performs Insert/Update/Delete operations across two different databases hosted on separate Azure SQL servers. The API uses a repository-level method to handle these operations, effectively following a distributed transaction pattern.
Authentication with the Azure SQL databases is managed using a user-assigned managed identity, which has the following permissions:
db_datareader, db_datawriter, db_executor

While running the API endpoint, I get the following error:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException:

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch+<ExecuteAsync>d__50.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)  
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Update.Internal.SqlServerModificationCommandBatch+<ExecuteAsync>d__15.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)  
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor+<ExecuteAsync>d__9.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)  
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor+<ExecuteAsync>d__9.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)  
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor+<ExecuteAsync>d__9.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)  
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager+<SaveChangesAsync>d__111.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)  
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager+<SaveChangesAsync>d__115.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)  
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy+<ExecuteAsync>d__30`2.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)  
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext+<SaveChangesAsync>d__63.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)  
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext+<SaveChangesAsync>d__63.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)  
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)  
at Shared.Infrastructure.Persistence.Context.ModuleDbContext+<SaveChangesAsync>d__5.MoveNext (Shared.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\DemoDbContext.cs:53)

Here is a snippet from DemoDbContext.cs:
public override async Task SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    return await base.SaveChangesAsync(true, cancellationToken);
}

In this setup, there are two separate DbContext files that inherit from DemoDbContext and use the SaveChangesAsync method for save operations.
What is the impact of granting db_owner permission on the overall method implementation, especially in the context of distributed transactions? Are there any potential security or performance implications I should be aware of?
Can anyone help me here with some code sample which will serve as a reference for my implementation?

What is the error message?  It may be unrelated to permissions.

Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft for your response. After further troubleshooting the issue in details I saw that the user assigned used in this case to connect to Azure SQL has  only  db_datareader. It does not have db_datawriter access. I updated the role permission and found working as expected.


Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException:

The Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException typically occurs when Entity Framework Core (EF Core) encounters an issue while attempting to save the changes to the database. This could be due to various reasons such as constraint violations, data type mismatches, or database connection issues.
To resolve this, you need to check the below issues if you are facing:

Constraint Violations: Check if you are not violating any constraint applied on the table like NOT NULL, UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY, FOREIGN KEY, CHECK, DEFAULT, CREATE INDEX.
Data Type Mismatches: Verify that the data being saved matches the database schema (e.g., string length, nullable columns, etc.).
Database Connection: Chech the permissions of the USER with which you are trying to connect the database.

